# Google Analytics in an Angular SPA

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, single-page-application

I've had GA setup in my Angular single page application for a while now. At the bottom of the main index.html I have the GA tracking code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i["GoogleAnalyticsObject"]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,"script","//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js","ga");
  ga("create", "UA-56056824-2", "auto");
  ga("send", "pageview");
</script>
```

Then, to make sure a new pageview is fired to Google every time the user enters a new view, I've added a listener for `viewContentLoaded` to then fire a new pageview to GA.

```
app.run(["$rootScope", "$location", "$window", function($rootScope, $location, $window){
  $rootScope.$on("$viewContentLoaded", function(event){
    $window.ga("send", "pageview", { page: $location.url() });
  });
}]);
```

This all works great, but I was noticing an extremely low bounce rate (3%). I've realised now what's happening. The user comes to the homepage and the GA script fires, sending a pageview of the homepage. Then once the javascript executes and the view loads, a second pageview is sent using the javascript above.

This is obviously giving incorrect pageview results and bounce rate. How do I correctly set this up?

Comment: I can suggest using Angulartics https://luisfarzati.github.io/angulartics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line from the script:

```
 ga("send", "pageview");
```

Comment: Based on the latest [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) documentation I'd suggest setting `ga('set', 'page', '$location.url()')`